# SQL Replication - FTP Snapshot

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication, snapshot

SQL transactional replication is setup but hitting an issue when trying to FTP the files over the internet, we have a VPN connection established to an external server.

The process could not retrieve file '*ServerNamePubName*/20171113081054/*TableName*.pre' from the FTP site '*FTPSITENAME*'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20033)

- Publication is enabled for Internet
- FTP is set to allow SSL connections
- Can see the external subscription against the pub

As far as I know the firewall rules have been set correctly, I am waiting on this being confirmed 100% by network team.

If my FTP connection string is incorrect I wouldn't expect the process to see the actual filename, but I am a little confused on the correct syntax with the 'Path from the FTP root folder' setting on the publication, various posts say I don't need the root info of the FTP but need to append FTP at the end?

Comment: I wonder if the issue is due to active vs passive mode file transfers.

Comment: Are you using FTP/FTPS/SFTP?

Comment: Unsure why this was migrated from DBA stack exchange as the error It specific to SQL replication, agree it may be FTP related but ....

Comment: Using SFTP port 22 has been opened and within the SQL publication settings I have entered the username and Password given to me by the sysadmin